# How to put tooltip description in each header cell ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-grid

i wont to use angulars bootstrap tooltip in header cell of ui-grid

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
 //some settings
 columnDefs: [
  {
   field: someId,
   displayName: 'Name',
   headerCellTemplate: 'linkToTemplate' //default headerCellTemplate with uib-tooltip={{tooltipDescription}},
   tooltipDescription: 'Tooltip description' //it's not working
  }
 ]
}
```

headerCellTemplate:

```
<div role="columnheader">
....
    <span class="ui-grid-header-cell-label">
    {{col.displayName}}
    </span>
    <span class="icon" uib-toolotp='{{col.tooltipDescription}}' tooltip-placement='right'></span>//it's not working
....
</div>
```

what is the right way to put tooltip description in each header cell?

Comment: I am not shure but why you do not use ui-tooltip?

 <button tooltip-placement="{{placement.selected}}" uib-tooltip="On the {{placement.selected}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip {{placement.selected}}</button>

Comment: sorry, it's was wrong example, i am using uib-tooltip in headerCellTemplate. The question is, how to put description for tooltip in template from $scope.gridOptions or $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs. I don't wont to hardcode tooltipDescription in template, like uib-toolotp='some description', because it is common template for all header cells.

Comment: use this   uib-tooltip-template=cell['template']

Comment: there seems to be a spelling mistake. Change `uib-toolotp` to `uib-tooltip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each cell has col.colDef property with access to all properties like field, displayName, tooltipDescription etc.